# Why does tensorflow saver takes so much time?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I am using `Tensorflow` to do speech recognition, and all parameters of my model is five millions. When I use `tf.saver` to save my Model, my pc gets stuck and I waited for several hours but it didn't finished. I don't know why?

Comment: Have you observed any errors?

Comment: however, there is no error.

Comment: It's hard to debug from the question you have provided. This gives good tips on how to provide good information: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask